# Jquery Ajax Post with body value from a form and print responses

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i have a ajax request to post data to api and get response. What i want to do is, how to pass a value from input field to the body data on ajax.

**here my form**

```
<input type="text" name="serial" />
<input type="submit" />
```

**here my ajax request**

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://www.example.com/api",
 beforeSend: function(xhr)
 { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password")); }, 
type: 'POST', 
dataType: 'json', 
contentType: 'application/json', 
processData: false, 
data: '{"serial":"252625"}', 
success: function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); }, 
error: function(){ 
alert("Cannot get data"); } 
});
```

I want to make the this part `data: '{"serial":"252625"}'` from a serial input filed programatically.

Thanks any suggestions,

Comment: On a side issue: by supplying user credentials in this way you make them visible to everyone. You should try and find a safer way to handle the authentication process and then save the state using a serverside session.

Answer (score 0):

Your form:

```
<input type="text" name="serial" id="serial" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

Javascript with Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.example.com/api",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
            }, 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            contentType: 'application/json', 
            processData: false,

            data: {
                serial: $('#serial').val()
            }, 

            success: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }, 
            error: function(error){ 
                alert("Cannot get data");
                console.log(error);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Hossein Zare, Thanks for the response, but why the first load of page showing the error alert cannot get data. How to make this after i put the value and submit if error?

Comment: @Bireon See the update and check your console log. I think it's because `http://www.example.com/api` is not a real url and the request can't find it , `404`.